# Проблема с созданием папки на sd накопителе?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

В общем, создаю некую папку. Таким вот образом:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MYDIRECTORY");
folder.mkdir();
```

В манифесте прописал:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

И вот в чем суть. Если после установки приложения сразу его запустить, то ничего не произойдет. Но если зайти в настройки и дать приложению там разрешение на `Память`, то создается папка, но только на внутреннем хранилище. Никто не знает как с этим бороться?

Comment: Android 6.0+, да? (:

Comment: надо runtime premission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Абсолютно верно написал @Suvitruf.

Что касается

> то создается папка, но только на внутреннем хранилище.

в официльной документации указано [getExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

**EDITED**

Метод getExternalStorageDirectory возвращает путь к хранилищу доступную для сторонних приложений (таких как галерея например). Это еще не означает что он вернет путь к SD карте. Сейчас на большнстве девайсах, не смотря на возможность расширять память SD картой, сэмулирована внешняя память, что то на подобии файловой системы на компьютере (аля диск D). Как то так своими словами.)))

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoverflow! Мне кажется, будет уместнее, если вы вкратце преведёте процитированный кусок документации -- не все знакомы с английским, чтобы с лёту понять.

Comment: Метод `getExternalStorageDirectory` возвращает путь к  хранилищу доступную для сторонних приложений (таких как галерея например). Это еще не означает что он вернет путь к SD карте. Сейчас на большнстве девайсах, не смотря на возможность расширять память SD картой, сэмулирована внешняя память, что то на подобии файловой системы на компьютере (аля диск D). Как то так своими словами.)))

Answer (score 1):

[`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) имеет protection level: **dangerous**.

На Android 6.0+ вам нужно такие разрешения [заправшивать в рантайме](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java).

Comment: Если можно, то опишите поподробнее как это правильно делается.